# I have been trying to draw pixels for a 3d game and I'm not getting any errors but it doen't work

Tags: java

This is my main class:

```
        package Main;

    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    import Graphics.Render;
    import Graphics.Screen;

    public class Run extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int[] pixels;
    private Render render;
    private Screen screen;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private Thread MainThread;
    private static Image Icon;
    private static final int Fps = 60;
    private final static int Width = 800;
    private final static int Height = 600;
    private static Boolean Running = false;

    public Run() {
        Start();
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        Icon = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("Resources/Textures/Icon.png")).getImage();
        screen = new Screen(Width, Height);
        img = new BufferedImage(Width, Height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.out.println("[System] Main Method Successfuly Loaded");
    }

    public void run() {
        while (Running == true) {
            MainThread.start();
            Render();
            Update();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void Start() {
        Running = true;
        if (Running == true) {
            System.out.println("[System] Starting...");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void Stop() {
        Running = false;
        try {
            MainThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void Render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        screen.render();

        for (int i = 0; i < Width * Height; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, Width, Height, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public synchronized void Update() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
        Run Run = new Run();
        Frame.add(Run);
        Frame.pack();
        Frame.setResizable(true);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setSize(Width, Height);
        Frame.setIconImage(Icon);
        Frame.setTitle("Space Infinity Pre-Alpha 1.0.0");
        Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("[System] Window Successfuly Created and Rendered");
    }
}
```

This is my main Render class:

```
    package Graphics;

    public class Render {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    public final int[] pixels;

    public Render(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height];
    }

    public void draw(Render render, int xoffset, int yoffset) {
        for (int y = 0; y < render.height; y++) {
            int yPix = y + yoffset;
            for (int x = 0; x < render.width; x++) {
                int xPix = x + xoffset;

                pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = render.pixels[x + y * render.width];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Screen class:

```
    package Graphics;

    import java.util.Random;

    public class Screen extends Render {
    private Render test;

    public Screen(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
        Random random = new Random();
        test = new Render(256, 256);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256 * 256; i++) {
            test.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        draw(test, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Now, I don't understand what I did wrong this worked before but now it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't draw the pixels?

Comment: In the "Run" class the method run needs the @Override directive, to implement that run method

Comment: I tried it, but that didn't do anything.